# Powershell Search AD via CSV and report on disabled / enable / non-existant users

Tags: powershell, active-directory

The script below has a CSV input with a column `samaccountname` and a list of users. When ran it generates a CSV report with 3 columns:

- AccountExists
- AccountDisabled
- samaccountname

If run in its present state it does indeed generate a report on whether the account is disabled and if it does exist, however if it encounters a user that does not exist in AD they are not added to the CSV report and the following error for each user is thrown:

> Cannot index into a null array. At line:4 char:75
>   + ... ($account=([adsisearcher]"(samaccountname=$($_.samaccountname))").fin
>   ...
>   +                                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

Is it possible instead for the non-existent users to be added to the CSV report under the column account exists with a value of `FALSE`

```
Import-CSV C:\ScriptRepository\Users.csv | ForEach-Object {
    New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
        samaccountname = $_.samaccountname
        AccountExists = [bool]($account=([adsisearcher]"(samaccountname=$($_.samaccountname))").findone()).count
        AccountDisabled = [bool]($account.properties.useraccountcontrol[0] -band 2)
    }
} | Export-Csv C:\ScriptRepository\UsersState.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Please update your question with an example of your "CSV input".

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you're not using the AD cmdlets?

Comment: Hi Bill, the CSV is correctly formatted with a column headed samaccountname withthe account names below it.

Comment: Hi Mark, no reason, if its possible it would be welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd handle it:

```
$ADS_UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE = 2

$searcher = [ADSISearcher] ""
$searcher.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(@("userAccountControl"))

Import-Csv "Users.csv" | ForEach-Object {
  $searcher.Filter = "(sAMAccountName=$($_.sAMAccountName))"
  $account = $searcher.FindOne()
  if ( $account ) {
    $exists = $true
    $disabled = ($account.Properties["useraccountcontrol"][0] -band $ADS_UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE) -ne 0
  }
  else {
    $exists = $false
    $disabled = "N/A"
  }
  [PSCustomObject] @{
    "sAMAccountName"  = $_.sAMAccountName
    "AccountExists"   = $exists
    "AccountDisabled" = $disabled
  }
}
```

Comment: Cheers Bill, that works exactly as needed, no error and has the non-existant accounts included. Thankyou very much for your time. It is very much appreciated.

Comment: No problem, glad it works for you. It should be pretty fast.

Comment: It is fast indeed, roughly 6 seconds for 644 users. Thanks again Bill.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by moving the logic to before the hashtable:

```
Import-CSV C:\ScriptRepository\Users.csv | ForEach-Object {
    $AccountExists = If ( (([adsisearcher]"(samaccountname=$($_.samaccountname))").FindOne()) ) { $true } else { $false }
    If ($AccountExists) { $AccountDisabled = [bool]($AccountExists.properties.useraccountcontrol[0] -band 2) } Else { $AccountDisabled = '' }

    New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
        samaccountname = $_.samaccountname
        AccountExists = $AccountExists
        AccountDisabled = $AccountDisabled
    }
} | Export-Csv C:\ScriptRepository\UsersState.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: This is only a hashtable in the sense that they are key->value pairs but it is absolutely not a hashtable object.  What you've created is a PSCustomObject.  A hashtable has different properties and methods and cannot be used as easily as a PSCustomObject with the traditional PoSh cmdlets (e.g. select, where, etc.).

Comment: See:  (New-Object PSObject -Property @{ 'name'='value' }).GetType();
(New-Object PSObject -ArgumentList @{ 'name'='value' }).GetType()

Comment: I was referring to the hashtable that is being passed in to the -Property parameter of New-Object which is then creating a PSCustomObject.

Comment: Hi mark, unfortunately when this is run the previous error now occurs for every account in the CSV:  Cannot index into a null array. At line:4 char:75 + ... ($account=([adsisearcher]"(samaccountname=$($_.samaccountname))").fin ... + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

Comment: I'm not really sure how this code is supposed to work?  $AccountExists ends up being a boolean but you're treating it as it it's returning the ADSISearcher object by referencing properties on it for $AccountDisabled... And even if it wasn't returning a boolean, you're returning the integer from the .count() method also...  ???

Comment: Apologies, .count -eq 1 was remnant from a previous attempt. I have removed it.